# I need a URL list button to email multiple contacts

Tags: custom-button, list-view, urlhacking, tag, list-button

My client would like to begin leveraging Salesforce Tags to cut down on custom field creation, and they're just handy in general. The trouble is, one contacts are tagged, there's nothing you can do with them (to my knowledge) without a custom list button.

They would like to, for instance, email the contacts with a particular tag.

I've tried to create a custom list button (URL) to email these contacts, and the usual fields (subject, related to, etc.) populate fine but I cannot get the multiple emails selected via checkbox to populate. Is this possible?

This is how it currently appears:
[image: Leveraging Salesforce tags to send emails from tag list view]

** **EDIT** ** And my simplified code:

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p6=This_Is_A_Test&p5={!Contact.Id}
```

Comment: do you want to use standard email send page?

Comment: Preferably, yes

Comment: can you pls share your button code?

Comment: Sure, it's very minimal... Added to my original post